# RemoveHandler in OpenSeadragon

Tags: openseadragon

I have problems to remove a handler from the viewer.

```
viewer.addHandler('viewport-change', function() {
     // do stuff works
});

viewer.addHandler('zoom', function() {
    if (viewer.viewport.getZoom() > threshold) {
        viewer.removeHandler('viewport-change', function() {
            console.log("removed");
        });
        console.log("Zoom:" + viewer.viewport.getZoom());
    }
});
```

I can see the output with the zoom factor, but I never saw the "removed" output.
Also just adding and removing the "viewport-change"-handler did not worked. removeAllHandlers seems to work, but I fail with removing only one handler.

What I really try to do is something like a swipe effect. If the image is not zoomed in and the left edge hits the viewer border i want to show next image. Maybe there is a better way to do that.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to make `removeHandler` work, it needs to be the exact same function that you used with `addHandler`, like so:

```
var viewportChangeHandler = function() {
     // do stuff works
};

viewer.addHandler('viewport-change', viewportChangeHandler);

viewer.addHandler('zoom', function() {
    if (viewer.viewport.getZoom() > threshold) {
        viewer.removeHandler('viewport-change', viewportChangeHandler);
        console.log("Zoom:" + viewer.viewport.getZoom());
    }
});
```

That said, if all you want to do is detect swipes, just a handler on `canvas-drag` (plus some additional logic of your own writing) should be sufficient.